# SQL Server Express does not start on running docker container (Windows)

Tags: docker, sql-server-express, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, server-core

**What I have done:**

- I have installed **Docker Desktop for Windows** on Windows 10 Anniversary
  Update
- I pulled a the image microsoft/windowsservercore
- I installed **SQL Server Express 2016** on a running container A of this image.
- I exited the container A
- I committed the container A to a new image sqlimage
- I run a new container B with the new sqlimage

**My Problem:**

On container A the SQL Server works correctly.
On container B the SQL Server could not be started.
When I try to start the service with net start "SQL Server (INST)" i  get following error: 
A service specific error occured: 5.

What is the difference between these two containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have their own image on the Docker Hub with SQL Server 2016 Express installed: [microsoft/mssql-server-2016-express-windows](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-2016-express-windows/). You can use that directly, or extend it with your own Dockerfile that starts:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-2016-express-windows
```

If you'd rather build your own, you can see how Microsoft do it from their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/manage/windows-containers/mssql-server-2016-express-windows/dockerfile) - and if you check the PowerShell script in the `CMD` instruction, it starts SQL Express like this:

```
start-service MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS
```

When you use `docker commit` to save a changed image, you're not changing the `CMD` that Docker will use when you run a new container from the image, so you're better off [building your image from a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

As to why the service is failing to start in your container B - that depends on the steps you took to install SQL, and the options you used when running the containers.

Comment: I tried to start the service with powershell and start-service. It does not start. I want do avoid download and install sqlserver at creating the container, becouse i want to run many containers and this would take too long. I wrote an answer with the steps i took to install the sql server. Thank You!

Comment: You can write a Dockerfile which contains `RUN` instructions to download the SQL Server installer, and run the setup. Those things only happen when you use `docker build` to produce the image. You can use `docker run` to start many containers from the same image, and they don't repeat any of the build instructions from the Dockerfile - only the `CMD` instruction which tells Docker what to do when containers start.

Comment: I solved it finally using the microsoft/mssql-server-2016-express-windows image and added my application to this.

Answer (score 0):

To Install the SQL Server i run:

```
SETUP.exe /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.ini  /SAPWD="XXXXXXX" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

ConfigurationFile:

```
[OPTIONS]
ACTION="Install"
ROLE="AllFeatures_WithDefaults"
ENU="True"
Setup will not display any user interface. 
QUIET="True"
QUIETSIMPLE="False"
UpdateEnabled="True"
ERRORREPORTING="False"
USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="True"
FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK
UpdateSource="MU"
HELP="False"
INDICATEPROGRESS="True"
X86="False"
INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
INSTANCENAME="XAM"
SQMREPORTING="False"
INSTANCEID="XAM"
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT-AUTORITÄT\NETZWERKDIENST"
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
COMMFABRICPORT="0"
COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"
COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"
MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"
ENABLERANU="True"
SQLCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$XAM"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"
SECURITYMODE="SQL"
INSTALLSQLDATADIR="C:\SQLData"
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"
TCPENABLED="1"
NPENABLED="0"
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
```

I run the container with

```
docker run -i --net=mytransparentnw --name B sqlimage
```

Answer (score 0):

My container didn't run, I looked at the log and there was a password error asking for at least 8 characters.
When creating the image, try to enter a password with 8 characters or more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).